# group by with a series of conditional statements

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, data-cleaning

I have a small dataset with about 20k rows that I need to filter out based on a series of conditions.

The rules are as follows:

1. Look for duplicates based on BusinessName, Address, City, State. If these values of are all duplicates, then I need to aggregate them based on a series of conditions below:
2. Look at Employee, if there is a 0 between the duplicates, drop the 0 value. If all Employee values are > 0, then only keep the row with the highest value for Employee
3. If Employee values are the same then move on to Sales and do the same. If there is a 0 in Sales, drop that row. If all Sales values are > 0, keep the row with the highest value for Sales.

So far i have been able to use a group_by() to carry out some of the steps. But when I compare the group_by to n_distinct(data$BusinessName), the values don't match up.

This is the code I have working so far, but i cant seem to workout the rest of the conditional statements.

```
data = data_group %>%
  group_by(BusinessName) %>%
  filter(Sales == max(Sales))  %>%
  ungroup()
```

Visual explanation of what I am looking for.

This:

[image: Original data]

Becomes this:

[image: Final Output]

Comment: Just add a `filter(Employee == max(Employee))` before your Sales `filter` step and this should work

Comment: Why is the last one Food Compnay selecting row 100 as filtered output.  Wouldn't that be the last row with 5000

Comment: @Julian_Hn solved it, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the `class` of 'Sales' column as there are `,` in between the digits, therefore the column may be either character or factor class.  An option is to do remove those `,`, convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric` and then do the `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data_group %>%
  mutate(Sales = as.numeric(str_remove_all(Sales, ","))) %>%
  group_by(BusinessName) %>%
  filter(Sales == max(Sales, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or if we want to also include the condition with 'Employee', it may be better to `arrange` the data based on the 'Employee' and 'Sales' and slice the first row

```
data_group %>%
    mutate(Sales = as.numeric(str_remove_all(Sales, ","))) %>%
    arrange(BusinessName, desc(Employee), desc(Sales)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Sales)) %>%
    group_by(BusinessName) %>%
    slice_head(n = 1)
```